# Trigger Lightning Email template

Tags: apex, email-template

I have create a Lightning email template related to Account. 
In the apex code I am referencing this email template, so that the email that goes out is based on this template. 
The email I receive is not the the template but what i have hard coded in the subject and body in the apex code.

[[image]][1

What changes do i make so that the email that goes out is based on the email template?

```
  public static void SendMail(String email,String recordId){
       EmailTemplate emailTemplate = [Select Id,Subject,Description,HtmlValue,DeveloperName,Body from EmailTemplate where name = 'VerifyDuplicateAccount'];
       Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
       String[] toAddresses = new String[]{email};
       mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
       mail.setSubject('Verify duplicate Account');
       mail.setPlainTextBody('Hi, This record is duplicate : '+recordId);
       mail.setBccSender(false);
       mail.setUseSignature(false);
       mail.saveAsActivity = false;
       mail.setTemplateID(emailTemplate.Id); 
       mail.setWhatId(recordId); //This is important for the merge fields in template to work
       Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });

}
```

Comment: Does the template subject and body display correctly if you remove the setSubject and setPlainTextBody in the apex? I know the setTemplateId should override it, but it's worth testing.

Comment: Why are you setting the body and subject if you want to use a template?  That will override the template, as explained in [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm).

Comment: I removed the setSubject and setPlainTextBody and got this error REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Missing targetObjectId with template what i understand from the documentation is that i have to use    `setTargetObjectId(targetObjectId)` where targetObjectId is the ID of the contact, lead, or user to which the email will be sent.